# Jenkins: Cucumber Trend report cannot find json file even though file exists

Tags: json, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Cucumber Trend Report plugin 1.3 on Jenkins v2.49. I have then added a Cucumber Trend Report post build action in my jenkins job. As soon as the job reached the post build action it gives the following error -

> ERROR: Step ‘Cucumber Trend Report’ aborted due to exception: 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source
>   '/home/xxx/slave/workspace/job_name/folder/reports/sample.json' does
>   not exist     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.cucumbertrendsreport.publish.CucumberTrendReportBuilder.perform(CucumberTrendReportBuilder.java:70)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)

The sample.json file exists. I do not understand why the plugin cannot find it.

P.S. - The job is executed on a slave agent.

**UPDATE -** The cucumber command in the build section is

RAILS_ENV=development cucumber  --format json -o reports/features_firstRun.json --format pretty --tags @doctor  ||:
cucumber --format pretty --format html @rerun.txt -o reports/features_rerun.html

The Post Build Section for cucumber trend report is
[Buid and Post Build page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLAnJ.jpg)

Comment: Please share your expression for locating the files. Jenkins has a setting where you need to specify either the file you are looking for or a pattern that will match the file.

Comment: Hi Thomas, the cucumber trend plugin has a section where the path of the json file is given. I have updated my answer with more details. Thanks

Comment: Use Ant syntax for locating your file in the correct directory. I.e. something like this: **/reports

Comment: Thanks for the tip Thomas. Will get back after i figure it out.

Comment: Turns out the plugin doesn't work with Jenkins 2.4. I setup Jenkins 1.625 on a test server and installed the plugin and it worked.